# Understanding "das Herz ging ihm danach auf" in Doktor Allwissend

Tags: meaning-in-context

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from [Doktor Allwissend](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Doctor_Allwissend_(1857)) in Brothers Grimm's collection.

> Es war einmal ein armer Bauer namens Krebs, der fuhr mit zwei Ochsen ein Fuder Holz in die Stadt und verkaufte es für zwei Taler an einen Doktor. Wie ihm nun das Geld ausbezahlt wurde, saß der Doktor gerade zu Tisch: da sah der Bauer, wie er schön aß und trank, und **das Herz ging ihm danach auf**, und er wäre auch gern ein Doktor gewesen. Also blieb er noch ein Weilchen stehen und fragte endlich, ob er nicht auch könnte ein Doktor werden. „O ja,“ sagte der Doktor, „das ist bald geschehen.“ „Was muß ich tun?“ fragte der Bauer. „Erstlich kauf dir ein Abcbuch, so ist eins, wo vorn ein Göckelhahn drin ist; zweitens mache deinen Wagen und deine zwei Ochsen zu Geld und schaff dir damit Kleider an und was sonst zur Doktorei gehört; drittens laß dir ein Schild malen mit den Worten „ich bin der Doktor Allwissend,“ und laß das oben über deine Haustür nageln.“ Der Bauer tat alles, wies ihm geheißen war.

**QUESTION**

What exactly does the clause mean, and how does it come to mean that?

**BACKGROUND**

If *das Herz geht jemandem nach einer Sache auf* is a set phrase, please tell me so and provide the exact meaning.

If it is not a set phrase, and the reader must put its meaning together from the meanings of of its components, please explain the process.  It might go, for example (and this may be totally wrong):

> *aufgehen* is for something to go off, or become more active and noticeable.  So, the heart went off, or began to act up.  Next, it went off to the peasant (from this we learn whose heart has been in question).  Finally, the heart went off after the food and drink (if *danach* refers to what went before).  Putting it all together, the peasant's heart went off after the food and drink. Or he craved them.

Finally perhaps you might add how poetic or plain, unusual or ordinary the structure is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Redensarten Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20geht%20das%20Herz%20auf&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) (index of [German] proverbs and sayings), it means

> jemand kommt in eine feierliche / glückliche Stimmung; jemand bekommt
>   das gute Gefühl, einem besonderen Ereignis beizuwohnen

Meaning

> someone gets into a good or celebratory mood; someone gets the feeling
>   they are witnessing or partaking in a special event

It is indeed a set phrase attributed to

> Das in dieser Redensart verwendete Bild verbindet die aufgehende Sonne
>   als Symbol einer frohen Stimmung mit dem Herzen als Sitz der Gefühle.
>   Die Redensart ist spätestens seit dem frühen 19. Jahrhundert
>   schriftlich belegt: "... muß dem verstocktesten Misathropen das Herz
>   aufgehen" (Zeitung für die elegante Welt, 1812, Nr. 88, 700)

Translation

> The image employed in this phrase combines the rising sun as symbol of
>   joyful feelings with the heart as the centre of feelings/emotions. The
>   phrase has been found in writing since no later than the early 19th
>   century: [example and source given]

I'd say the phrase is indeed somewhat poetic but common. It wouldn't be unusual to say something like

> Schau mal die Hündin mit ihrem Wurf Welpen, da geht einem ja das Herz
>   auf.

Translated:

> Look at the bitch [canine, not insult!] with her litter of puppies,
>   doesn't that make you feel all warm inside.

The use of *danach* is rarely found today, after some research I found it in one modern document, the *BOTSCHAFT VON JOHANNES PAUL II. ZUM WELTMISSIONSSONNTAG 2000* (*Message from John Paul II. for World Missionary Day 2000*):

> Wir wissen, daß ihre Mühen und ihr Leid nicht verlorengehen werden,
>   sondern der Sauerteig sind, der **im Herzen anderer Apostel die
>   Sehnsucht danach aufgehen** läßt, sich der edlen Sache des Evangeliums
>   zu widmen.

Translation

> We know that their labour and suffering shall not be in vain, but
>   rather will be the rising dough, that will raise the longing in the
>   hearts of other apostels to dedicate themselves to the noble cause of
>   the gospels.

As you can see from the highlighted part, this isn't even the exact same phrasing nor meaning, but is the closest to a modern combination of the phrase that includes the craving aspect.

Comment: So, the peasant's response was delight, not craving.  Of course craving might have followed, but the immediate thing said of him was delight. This sort of subtle difference can matter a great deal in a fairy tale, where attitude could mean life or death. Thank you also for the reference to Redensarten Index.

Comment: The problem is of course that there is no *nach* in your example.

Comment: @CarstenS Indeed!  If someone could work *nach* into the structure and consider how that might change things (perhaps give a tinge of craving to delight), that would be very helpful.

Comment: Good point, my first reading of the special context of the fairy tale wasn't even the craving implication of _danach_. It's a bit archaic, will have to think of an example that someone would actually use nowadays. Unless you don't care :)

Comment: After doing some reading up, I just can't find any **modern** context where the _danach_ would still be used. With one remarkable exception, which I've put into the answer.